# Using ajax to call method in view.py (Pyramid)

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, pyramid

I've been trying to figure out how to use ajax with the pyramid framework by trying to call a method in my `view.py` file. Somewhat new to python so I think I've probably made a mistake with my url in my ajax call since it can't seem to find the file I'm pointing to(maybe too much `ASP` influence).

Here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../views.py/new_sheet",  <---trouble with this
        type: "post",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Yay!");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

and this is the method I am trying to call:

```
@view_config(route_name="test", renderer='templates/main.html')
def new_sheet(self,request):
    test = "hello"
    return dict(test=test)
```

any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the URL you want to call, e.g. http:://localhost:8080/myapp/test (since you configuerd to map test to the view)
What you do is trying to call the python function directly from your browser, which is not possible,

Comment: thank you good sir. I will mark your answer in 6 minutes. I guess I tried to use .ASP style too much